# Uncaught TypeError: *** is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following JavaScript code automatically generated from a CMS.

```
...
function setEmail() {
    alert("Hello");
}
...

{if(window&&$){$(window).load(function(){var _rsm741573_01 = findControl("CrmTextField_C015");
   if(_rsm741573_01)bindEvent('changes',_rsm741573_01,function(s,a){
      (function(y,z){
        setEmail()(y,z);
      })(s,a);
   });
})}}
```

And I always have this error when change happens on the field:

> (index):640 Uncaught TypeError: setEmail(...) is not a function

How to declare the function in order to avoid this error?

Comment: could you put a breakpoint or a debugger statement and then check the stack trace and see what is global and what not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're calling `setEmail()(y,z);`. That is, you're calling `setEmail()`, then taking the return value from that function and trying to again call that as a function, passing in `y` and `z`. Your `setEmail` function does not return anything at all, so it's definitely not returning another function which expects two arguments.

From context, it's unclear *why* you're calling `setEmail()(y,z);`, so depending on whether that's intentional or not, you either need to remove one set of parens so you're only calling one function, or rewrite `setEmail` to return another function, depending on what you're actually aiming to accomplish here.

Comment: The second part of the code is generated automatically by a plugin in the CMS. I cannot choose how the function is called :(

Comment: I found the problem, I had () after the function name in the plugin